# UIImagePickerController: Clip Length & Frames Per Second

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller, frame-rate, ios-camera

Is there a way to configure UIImagePickerController to capture photo bursts at a specific length or under a predetermined number of frames per second?

Comment: You could use this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10344637/capture-60fps-in-iphone-app

Comment: The AVFoundation Class is a solution to the general problem but not a direct answer to my question. A subquestion of mine is left unanswered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19425429/how-to-set-video-capture-frame-rate